# how to 301 redirect URL with %3E character

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this weird URL, `/andy-sixx-2012-short-hair%3Eandy`. I've tried this:

```
Redirect 301 /andy-sixx-2012-short-hair%3Eandy http://mysite.com/page.html
```

but that fails. I can redirect something like `/andy-sixx-2012-short-hairandy` no problem so the issue seems to be the **%3E** character. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Why is the url url-encoded?

Answer (score 0):

The URI is decodeded before modules like mod_alias or mod_rewrite gets to process them, thus you need to match against `>` and not `%3E`:

```
Redirect 301 /andy-sixx-2012-short-hair>andy http://mysite.com/page.html
```